# In Flutter App I want to implement translation using google translate api

Tags: flutter, google-translate

In My App I want to translate language using google tanslation just like website but the problem is due to continuous api call it has exceeded User Rate Limit. So is there any way to implement google translate like website in flutter  [As you can see in above given image this same way can i implement it in flutter?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqiFi.png)

I have tried many packages like google_translate, translator but it slows down app or gives 429 error due to continuous api call.